# VexIQ brain not responding to controller

Tags: robotc

I have been writing code for a vexIQ robot and my code is not working. A command that only turns on the motor works, but as soon as I add the controller it stops working. I am not getting any error messages on the computer or the brain, but the robot is not responding to the controller. The controller is on and connected to the brain, so I m not sure that is going on.

Here is the code:

```
task main(){
    while(1==1){
        motor[port1] = vexRT[ChA]/2;
    }
}
```